# bash - count, process, and increment thru multiple "Tasks" in log file

Tags: bash

I have log files that are broken down into between 1 and 4 "Tasks". In each "Task" there are sections for "WU Name" and "estimated CPU time remaining". Ultimately, I want to the bash script output to look like this 3 Task example;

```
Task 1    Mini_Protein_binds_COVID-19_boinc_    0d:7h:44m:28s
Task 2    shapeshift_pair6_msd4X_4_f_e0_161_    0d:4h:14m:22s
Task 3    rep730_0078_symC_reordered_0002_pr    1d:1h:38m:41s
```

So far; I can count the Tasks in the log. I can isolate x number of characters I want from the "WU Name". I can convert the "estimated CPU time remaining" in seconds to days:hours:minutes:seconds. And I can output all of that into 'pretty' columns. Problem is that I can only process 1 Task using;

```
# Initialize counter
counter=1

# Count how many iterations
cnt_wu=`grep -c "WU name:" /mnt/work/sec-conv/bnc-sample3.txt`

# Iterate the loop for cnt-wu times
while [ $counter -le ${cnt_wu} ]
do
    core_cnt=$counter
    wu=`cat /mnt/work/sec-conv/bnc-sample3.txt | grep -Po 'WU name: \K.*' | cut -c1-34`
    sec=`cat /mnt/work/sec-conv/bnc-sample3.txt | grep -Po 'estimated CPU time remaining: \K.*' | cut -f1 -d"."`
    dhms=`printf '%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($sec/86400)) $(($sec%86400/3600)) $(($sec%3600/60)) \ $(($sec%60))`
    echo "Task ${core_cnt}" $'\t' $wu $'\t' $dhms | column -ts $'\t'
    counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

Note: /mnt/work/sec-conv/bnc-sample3.txt is a static one Task sample only used for this scripts dev.

What I can't figure out is the next step which is to be able to process x number of multiple Tasks. I can't figure out how to leverage the while/counter combination properly, and can't figure out how to increment through the occurrences of Tasks.

**Adding bnc-sample.txt (contains 3 Tasks)**

```
1) -----------
   name: Rosetta@home
   master URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/
   user_name: XXXXXXX
   team_name:
   resource share: 100.000000
   user_total_credit: 10266.993660
   user_expavg_credit: 512.420495
   host_total_credit: 10266.993660
   host_expavg_credit: 512.603669
   nrpc_failures: 0
   master_fetch_failures: 0
   master fetch pending: no
   scheduler RPC pending: no
   trickle upload pending: no
   attached via Account Manager: no
   ended: no
   suspended via GUI: no
   don't request more work: no
   disk usage: 0.000000
   last RPC: Wed Jun 10 15:55:29 2020

   project files downloaded: 0.000000
GUI URL:
   name: Message boards
   description: Correspond with other users on the Rosetta@home message boards
   URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/forum_index.php
GUI URL:
   name: Your account
   description: View your account information
   URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/home.php
GUI URL:
   name: Your tasks
   description: View the last week or so of computational work
   URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/results.php?userid=XXXXXXX
   jobs succeeded: 117
   jobs failed: 0
   elapsed time: 2892439.609931
   cross-project ID: 3538b98e5f16a958a6bdd2XXXXXXXXX

======== Tasks ========
1) -----------
   name: shapeshift_pair6_msd4X_4_f_e0_161_X_0001_0001_fragments_abinitio_SAVE_ALL_OUT_946179_730_0
   WU name: shapeshift_pair6_msd4X_4_f_e0_161_X_0001_0001_fragments_abinitio_SAVE_ALL_OUT_946179_730
   project URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/
   received: Mon Jun  8 09:58:08 2020
   report deadline: Thu Jun 11 09:58:08 2020
   ready to report: no
   state: downloaded
   scheduler state: scheduled
   active_task_state: EXECUTING
   app version num: 420
   resources: 1 CPU
   estimated CPU time remaining: 26882.771040
   slot: 1
   PID: 28434
   CPU time at last checkpoint: 3925.896000
   current CPU time: 4314.761000
   fraction done: 0.066570
   swap size: 431 MB
   working set size: 310 MB
2) -----------
   name: rep730_0078_symC_reordered_0002_propagated_0001_0001_0001_A_v9_fold_SAVE_ALL_OUT_946618_54_0
   WU name: rep730_0078_symC_reordered_0002_propagated_0001_0001_0001_A_v9_fold_SAVE_ALL_OUT_946618_54
   project URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/
   received: Mon Jun  8 09:58:08 2020
   report deadline: Thu Jun 11 09:58:08 2020
   ready to report: no
   state: downloaded
   scheduler state: scheduled
   active_task_state: EXECUTING
   app version num: 420
   resources: 1 CPU
   estimated CPU time remaining: 26412.937920
   slot: 2
   PID: 28804
   CPU time at last checkpoint: 3829.626000
   current CPU time: 3879.975000
   fraction done: 0.082884
   swap size: 628 MB
   working set size: 513 MB
3) -----------
   name: Mini_Protein_binds_COVID-19_boinc_site3_2_SAVE_ALL_OUT_IGNORE_THE_REST_0aw6cb3u_944116_2_0
   WU name: Mini_Protein_binds_COVID-19_boinc_site3_2_SAVE_ALL_OUT_IGNORE_THE_REST_0aw6cb3u_944116_2
   project URL: https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/
   received: Mon Jun  8 09:58:47 2020
   report deadline: Thu Jun 11 09:58:46 2020
   ready to report: no
   state: downloaded
   scheduler state: scheduled
   active_task_state: EXECUTING
   app version num: 420
   resources: 1 CPU
   estimated CPU time remaining: 27868.559616
   slot: 0
   PID: 30988
   CPU time at last checkpoint: 1265.356000
   current CPU time: 1327.603000
   fraction done: 0.032342
   swap size: 792 MB
   working set size: 668 MB
```

Again, I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution, the `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Also, this could be reduced to (probably) one `awk` script/process and the code would be easier to understand and extend. Sorry, don't have time today to expand on this idea. Good luck.

Comment: Sample input, not just output, would be useful.

Comment: I agree with @Shawn, `bnc-sample3.txt` needs to be provided to fully understand and be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @GillesQuenot for the tip and the link!

Comment: You should reduce the issue in a minimal & reproducible fashion if you want to get help.   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)